# React Native Debugger prevents network requests

Tags: react-native

I'm working on a React Native app, testing in an android emulator. I've used the standalone React Native Debugger app as well as the debugger that opens in Chrome. In the Chrome window, the Network tab shows no activity, so that's no help. In the standalone debugger, the same is true until you right-click and choose Enable Network Inspect. The problem I'm having is that after I enable network inspecting in the debugger, all network requests fail - the inspector shows their status going from Pending to Canceled after a few seconds. I can see in my server logs that no requests are coming in. It's like debugger itself is somehow blocking the requests.

I've set up adb to run as root. When I run `react-native run-android` the output includes `Running adb -s emulator-5554 reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081`, so I think things are starting up fine. The network requests from the app (login etc.) work fine (a typical URL would be http://10.0.2.2:2080/api/LoginScreenController/GetIdentityStatus), until I choose "enable network inspect" in the debugger, at which point all network requests fail as described above.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I know that I'm too late but perhaps it will save time for somebody.
During the update of the react-native, I did update the version of the **react-native-reanimated** from v1 => v2, and after it, I faced the same behavior.
Version 2 requires to enable Hermes engine if it won't be enabled then all the requests will be in **pending** status